# Multiple args in custom print

Tags: python, printing

I define `debug_print()`:

```
def debug_print(info):
  print("[FOO] :",info)
```

I expect I can call like normal print like this:

```
name = 'Ujang'
debug_print(name, 'is winner!'); # I expect [FOO] : Ujang is winner!
```

But it gave me error

```
TypeError: debug_print() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I tried redefine `debug_print` parameter with using pointer symbol
`def debug_print(*info)` but it's showing tuple format.

```
# output
[FOO] : ('Ujang', 'is winner!')
```

Comment: `def debug_print(*info): print('[FOO]:', ' '.join(map(str, info)))`

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) standard library module.

Comment: @SUTerliakov good idea, I didn't know all this time.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. `*` is a sequence unpacking operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join()` function without `map()` as follows:

```
def debug_print(*info):
  print("[FOO] :", ' '.join(info))
  
name = 'Ujang'
debug_print(name, 'is winner!')
```

**Output:**

```
[FOO] : Ujang is a winner!
```

Also, as @KellyBundy suggested, you can take advantage of the `print()` function and pass `*info` as a parameter, so the print function will automatically convert all of its values to string:

```
def debug_print(*info):
  print("[FOO] :", *info)
  
name = 'Ujang'
debug_print(name, 'is winner!')
```

Comment: ... `map` was used because it is a logging function, so `debug_print(1, 'this')` should not fail

Comment: @KellyBundy and this is much prettier, could you post it as a separate answer?

Comment: @suterliakov I agree. Didn't notice that `*info` just unpacked all its parameters right as string

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is not how things work in python.
clearly, it is seen you pass two args but receive one in func,
bind name in your string, and pass as a single argument
like this.

```
def debug_print(info):
    print("[FOO] :",info)

name = 'Ujang'
debug_print(f'{name}is winner!')
```

Output: `[FOO] : Ujangis winner!`